# my CSV attachment is empty! PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel, email, csv

Im trying to take data from the database and display it in a CSV file which is both downloadable and emailed to someone. I have managed to get the downloadable file working and it displays all of the correct data. It also sends a CSV file to the necessary person but that CSV file is empty and no data is displayed in it.

Here is my code:

```
    $myroot = "../../";
    include($myroot . "inc/functions.php");
        // output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
        header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=surveys.csv');
        $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
// Create CSV file
fputcsv($output, array('Name', 'Branch', 'Website','Company', 'Question1', 'Question2', 'Question3', 'Question4', 'Question5'));

$mysql_connection = db_connect_enhanced('*****','*****','*****','*****');
$query='SELECT * FROM *****.*****';
$surveys = db_query_into_array_enhanced($mysql_connection, $query);
$count = count($surveys);
$data = array();
    for($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++){
    $data[] = array($surveys[$i]['FeedbackName'], $surveys[$i]['BranchName'], $surveys[$i]['FeedbackWebsite'], $surveys[$i]['FeedbackCompany'], $surveys[$i]['Question1'], $surveys[$i]['Question2'], $surveys[$i]['Question3'], $surveys[$i]['Question4'], $surveys[$i]['Question5']);  
}

foreach( $data as $row )  
{  
    fputcsv($output, $row, ',', '"');  
}  
fclose($output);  

$encoded = chunk_split(base64_encode($output));

// create the email and send it off

$subject = "File you requested from RRWH.com";
$from = "*****@*****.com";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
   boundary="----=_NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC"' . "\n";

$message = '

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

------=_NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC
Content-Type: text/plain;
       charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello

We have attached for you the PHP script that you requested from http://rrwh.com/scripts.php
as a zip file.

Regards

------=_NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;  name="';

$message .= "surveys.csv";
$message .= '"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="';
$message .= "surveys.csv";
$message .= '"

';
$message .= $encoded;
$message .= '

------=_NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC--

';
mail("*****@*****.com", $subject, $message, $headers, "-f$from");
```

I've spent a day and a half on this but I cant see the problem. Could someone please point it out to me as to why the attached CSV file is empty?

i'm getting kind of desperate and stressed out :( please someone help me.

Comment: If possible I'd suggest using a library to handle mail, SwiftMailer would really make this task simpler.

Comment: I feel like I am almost there with the code I have I would really like to keep it instead of scrapping it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`base64_encode()` expects the parameter to be a string and you  give it a (closed) resource.
Try to read the resource into a string, or use `file_get_contents` or build your string while you write into the resource.

Update:

Try and replace

```
foreach( $data as $row )  
{  
    fputcsv($output, $row, ',', '"');  
} 
fclose($output);  
$encoded = chunk_split(base64_encode($output));
```

by

```
$myoutput = '"Name","Branch","Website","Company","Question1","Question2","Question3","Question4","Question5"';
foreach( $data as $row )  
{  
    $myoutput .= "\"".implode('","',$row)."\"\n";
    fputcsv($output, $row, ',', '"');  
} 
fclose($output);  
$encoded = chunk_split(base64_encode($myoutput));
```

This way, everything you write into your output you also write into a new variable (`$myoutput`). Since this is a string you can use it with `base64_encode()`.

Comment: sorry i dont understand. how do I read the resource into a string? or how do i use file_get_contents?

Comment: Thankyou!!! that small change has fixed it and it now works :) 48 hours of this crap and you solved it so easily haha thanks again

Comment: Please keep in mind that I would consider this a "hack". It's not elegant but it works... most of the time.

Comment: i will...there is one more small issue...the CSV file is filled with the data now which is great...but the column headers are not there at the top (Name, Branch, Website etc etc) how come they have not gone into the CSV file also?

Comment: Only the string `$myoutput` appears in the file. I updated my answer.

Comment: thats half done it. only thing is the headers begin at '2"' of the "Questions2" header...all preceding ones are missing

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how this can be :/